# How should I install flooring over fresh concrete?

Tags: concrete, subfloor, vinyl-flooring

I have fresh concrete poured in my basement. Planing to use Metrofloor Engage Select vinyl plank for most of the floor. Contemplating ceramic tile for the bathroom if vinyl is not good enough for that.
What would be the best combination of layers under the vinyl? Would the same combination work under tile? (Assuming I will let the concrete dry to the appropriate level.)
Some choices I've researched so far:

-Seal the leftover moisture in the concrete using urethane adhesive under plywood

or

-Let the concrete dry forever, using something like DRIcore Subfloor Panel

If gluing, use plywood or OSB?

T&G is good or hard to work with? (contractors don't seem to like it)

What goes between the vinyl and the sub floor if anything?

Any other ideas?

The vinyl plank installation guide does say that it can go over concrete, but "concrete that exhibits high levels of Moisture Vapor Emissions/ Hydrostatic pressure in combination with high levels of alkalinity provides a substance that is highly corrosive. No floor covering, including ENGAGE,can withstand the long-term corrosive nature
of this chemical. If testing determines that the level of Vapor Emissions/ Hydrostatic pressure exceeds 8 pounds using the Calcium chloride test and/or a P.H. test indicates alkalinity levels in excess of 9, steps must be taken to separate ENGAGE from the source of the corrosive effect of this chemical."

Also, vinyl directly on concrete will be cold and loud when walking on it.
So I'm looking for something to separate the vinyl from the concrete and add a bit of thermo/sound insulation.
Maybe something like [SnapLock](http://www.snaplockdancefloors.com/floor.html) base floor and QuietWalk or [FloorMuffler](http://www.homedepot.com/p/FloorMuffler-100-sq-ft-25-ft-x-48-in-x-2-mm-Underlayment-0264049/204077418)

Answer (score 1):

First you should wait a minimum of 3 months before installing flooring on basement concrete.  This is usually a minimum.  I would suggest not sealing it either.  If its not sealed 100% you just made issue worse.

I am pretty sure I installed these on a house last year too.  I recall that they are all "rubber" (vinyl).  I liked them a lot.  I recall too calling the manufacturer # and them telling me they would suggest no underlayment under concrete.  My first reaction was this was odd since almost all floating floor manufacturers want something under but it makes sense.  Your underlayment will hold water - the planks won't.  So minimal water should dry quickly with nothing - and that is what we did.

Also I don't think you glue these - they have a good click lock system.  Read the instructions or call them but almost positive glue isn't an option.

As for dricore that is a totally different thing.  You are doubling/tripling the install and money.  I for one wouldn't think about putting dricore down in a new basement.  I have many reasons but lets just say if I have a problem in the future I don't want to deal with 5000 pounds of dricore tiles.

And for the tile part - it is nothing like the plank flooring.  You would simply use thinset then tile (maybe a binding agent).

Answer (score 0):

Where I live, basements are not common since we never get a freeze here so giving under layers for basements are out of my experience.

But for laying vinyl planks over new concrete, here are some general guidelines.  First, have patience.  You need to let the concrete cure for a couple of months before you do anything.  Second, you need to test the moisture content of the concrete as this will determine how aggressive you will need to be on the vapor barrier.  In my area it is fairly dry and the barest is only needed.  Third, you need to let your flooring sit in the install area for at least a week so it's humidity levels match that of it's environment.

Vinyl plank flooring typically is install as a floating floor to allow it to expand and contract with the temp/moisture changes of its environment.  To allow it to float, a thin foam pad is laid down first and the floor is then laid on top of this.  The floor is not attached to the pad or sub floor and around the outside of the room and expansion gap is given floor the floor to move with.  The expansion gap can be hide using baseboards and thresholds that have a cut out for the floor to move under.

I do not recommend using vinyl plank in the bathroom as it is impossible to correctly install it in there and vinyl plank also just doesn't deal with standing water very well.